# If $\cos^6 (x) + \sin^4 (x)=1$, find $x$ if $x\in [0, \dfrac {\pi}{2}]$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos^6 (x) + \sin^4 (x)=1$, find $x$ if $x\in [0, \dfrac {\pi}{2}]$

My attempt:
$$\cos^6 (x) + \sin^4 (x)=1$$
$$\cos^6 (x) + (1-\cos^2 (x))^{2}=1$$
$$\cos^6 (x) + 1 - 2\cos^2 (x) + \cos^4 (x) = 1$$
$$\cos^6 (x) + \cos^4 (x) - 2\cos^2 (x)=0$$

Comment: Try letting $t=\cos^2(x)$ then the equation becomes $t^3+t^2-2t=0$ and we can factorise $ t $ to solve a quadratic.

Comment: You recieved 6 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Clearly, $\sin x=0\iff\cos^2x=?,$

$\cos x=0\iff\sin^2x=?$ are solutions

For $0< a<1,$ $$a^6<a^4<a^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint — using this changing variable $y  = cos^2(x)$ —
$$y^3 + y^2-2y = 0 \Rightarrow y(y^2+y-2) = 0 \Rightarrow y(y+2)(y-1) = 0 $$

As $y = cos^2(x)$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$:
$$y = 0, 1 \Rightarrow cos^2(x) = 0, 1 \Rightarrow x = 0, \frac{\pi}{2},$$
for $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If we rewrite $u = \cos^2 x$ and factor, the equation becomes $$(u + 2) u (u - 1) = 0 .$$

**Alternative hint** We have $\cos^6 x \leq \cos^2 x$ and $\sin^4 x \leq \sin^2 x$, and in both cases equality holds (for $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$) only for $x = 0, \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\cos x = c, \sin x = s$.

$c^6 + s^4 = 1$

$c^6 + s^4 = c^2 + s^2$

$c^2(c^4-1)+s^2(s^2-1) = 0$

$c^2(c^4-1)-s^2c^2=0$

$c^2(c^4-1-s^2) = 0$

$c^2((c^2+1)(c^2-1)-s^2) = 0$

$-s^2c^2(c^2+2) = 0$

The only real zeroes occur when $\sin x = 0$ or $\cos x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1=\cos^6x+\sin^4x\leq\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1,$$ which gives the following system.
$$\cos^6x=\cos^2x$$ and $$\sin^4x=\sin^2x.$$
Can you end it now?